# Click event not firing after adding jqueryui css

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I come to strange issue with jQueryUi css. Once I reference it the click event doesn't fire once I add jqueryui css.

Example without jQueryUI css (http://jsfiddle.net/dynamikus/CffPt/3/) 
Example with jQueryUI css (http://jsfiddle.net/dynamikus/CffPt/2/)

Could someone help me out?
Thnx

--Edit
I am testing it on Windows 7/ Chrome :21.0.1180.79

Comment: the both do the same thing for me :/

Comment: How could CSS affect a click event?

Comment: Hmmm strange I am using lates version of FF and Chrome

Comment: @j08691 It couldn't.  Something else is going on.

Comment: It's not working in chrome.. are you guys clicking on the little image in the lower right?

Comment: @Vega no the css is not included in both links

Comment: @j08691 Try this senario in Chrome 21.0.1180.79

Comment: The problem lies in this piece of code `.selectable({ filter: "li" })`

Comment: @j08691 Are you sure? I just removed and the event is not firing againg?

Comment: When I remove it I get the alert.

Comment: It's a z-index issue.. http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/CffPt/4/  If you change the z-index it clicks fine

Comment: @wirey post it as answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a z-index issue..  http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/CffPt/4/ If you change the z-index it clicks fine

Answer (score 1):

It does work when you'd change the click-event to an mousedown-event.

It appears to be the z-index. Change the z-index of your zoom-elements to 99999 (for example) and you'll notice that it will work. The z-index is a style property, so adding a CSS can indeed mess up your behavior here :)

http://jsfiddle.net/3Z9yf/
You'll notice that the first button doesn't work (default z-index), while the second one will (has the z-index).

Comment: I removed all the mousedown even the filter still no results http://jsfiddle.net/dynamikus/CffPt/5/